# Javascript replace string by another String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following string in javascript.

```
var str = 'P24 + P33'; //p24 is just exp. it will be any number i.e. P98
```

I Want to replace this string into following string using jquery replace.

```
var str = "$('#p24').val() + $('#p33').val()";
```

Comment: Your intent is not clear at all. What is the output you're trying to achieve? What do the `P24` and `P33` variables contain?

Comment: My Question is very simple I just want to replace 'P24 + P33' to "$('#p24').val() + $('#p33').val()" using javascript.

Comment: You should search before ask a question. There are to much related topic with yours.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var str = 'P24 + P33'; //p24 is just exp. it will be any number i.e. P98
var str_array = str.split(" + ");
console.log("Original string: "+str);
for(var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++){
  str_array[i] = $("#"+str_array[i]).html();
}
var replaced_string = str_array.join(" + ");
console.log("Replaced string: "+replaced_string);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="P24">this is P24</div>
<div id="P33">this is P33</div>
```